# How do I convert a double value to int128_t?

Tags: c++, boost

I have replaced unsigned long long in Closed-Form Formula Fibonacci code to int128_t from Boost library:

```
int128_t FibFormula(int n, int128_t a, int128_t b)
{
    return (1 / sqrt(5.0) * (pow(((1 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2), n) - (pow(((1 - sqrt(5.0)) / 2), n))));
}
```

It is a closed-form formula algorithm to get a Fibonacci number. I get this error:

no suitable constructor exists to convert from "double" to "boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<128U, 128U, boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::unchecked, void>, boost::multiprecision::et_off>"

It there a way to convert a double value to int128_t? If not, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: FWIW, you should really be sticking with integer math, or at least fixed precision.  `double` being a floating point type only has about 16 digits of precision, so for bigger numbers, you are going to get inexact results.

Comment: Because this conversion is lossy, `boost::multiprecision::number` requires a `static_cast`.  And converting from `int128_t` to `double` back to `int128_t` is _certainly lossy_.

Comment: I was trying to take a sqrt from an integer, but it says: "more than one instance of overloaded function matches the argument list: function template (declared at line 673 of) function template (declared at line 337 of) argument types are: (int)"

Comment: That's because there's a `sqrt (float)` and a `sqrt (double)`, and an `int` can convert to either equally well.  Solution: cast the `int` to the type you want `sqrt` to use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.